# GetViewForHeader works in the simulator but not working on the device

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

So i have a GetViewForHeader override and it works great in the simulator. When I debug the app on the device (both iPad and iPhone) no styling is applied. There is no error and the GetViewForHeader code is definitely NOT being run. TitleForHeader etc is tho. Odd!

```
    public override string TitleForHeader (UITableView tableView, int section)
{
    return tableItems[section].Name;
}

public override UIView GetViewForHeader(UITableView tableView, int section)
{
    // THIS DOES NOT FIRE ON THE DEVICE - BUT IT DOES ON THE SIMULATOR
    return BuildSectionHeaderView(tableItems[section].Name);
}

public static UIView BuildSectionHeaderView(string caption) {
    UIView view = new UIView(new System.Drawing.RectangleF(0,0,320,20));
    view.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;

    UILabel label = new UILabel();
    label.Opaque = false;
    label.TextColor = UIColor.FromRGB (190, 0, 0);
    label.Font = UIFont.FromName("Helvetica-Bold", 16f);
    label.Frame = new System.Drawing.RectangleF(5,10,315,20);
    label.Text = caption;
    view.AddSubview(label);
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `GetViewForHeader` method is only called if `GetHeightForHeader` returns a non-zero integer, so ensure you are implementing the `GetHeightForHeader` method and returning an appropriate height.

It's also worth noting that the `TitleForHeader` method should not be implemented if using header views.

Comment: I've now edited the code - removed the TiteForHeader and added the GetHeightForHeader. I'm now getting a different error: Exception of type 'MonoTouch.Foundation.You_Should_Not_Call_base_In_This_Method' was thrown.

Comment: Is the error coming from the same place or is it from another file now? I'm speculating without seeing more code, but all I can suggest is that you make sure you are definitely using the `override` keyword on your `GetHeightForHeader` method. Failing that, it's likely that fixing those issues has exposed another problem.